# Connect SEGA MegaDrive 2 to hdtv

Tags: sega-genesis

I've recently bought a Megadrive 2 but when i try to connect it to my tv via RCA cable, always remains with no signal.

This is my MegaDrive:[image: megadrive front]

This is my Megadrive back:[image: megadrive back]

[image: megadrive back 2]

This are my TV components: [image: tv components]

This is the RCA cable i've bought: [image: rca cable]

And finally my TV sources: [image: tv sources]

How can i connect the megadrive to my TV? Am i missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Is that a Sega-specific cable? According to Wikipedia, it sounds like the Mega Drive / Genesis used specialized cables:

> The back of the model 1 console provides a radio frequency output port (designed for use with antenna and cable systems) and **a specialized 8-pin DIN port**, which both provide video and audio output. Both outputs produce monophonic sound; a headphone jack on the front of the console produces stereo sound.[107] On the model 2, the DIN port, radio frequency output port, and headphone jack are replaced by **a 9-pin mini-DIN port** on the back for composite video, RGB and stereo sound, and the standard RF switch.

Comment: RCA to SCART adapter solved the problem